# User.Username Field Accepts More Than 80 Characters?

Tags: configuration, user-record

The length of `UserName` field in the standard `User` object is 80 characters (ie. `Text(80)`).

Recently in my production org, a `User` record was created with a `Username` more than 80 characters. Due to this issue, one of the batch jobs in ETL broke.

Has anybody faced this issue? As per our functionality, `User` record gets created via `Apex` code. There is no special character present.

I am trying to investigate how Salesforce allowed an 81 character `Username`.

Can anyone assist me on this issue?

Comment: Can you share the problem UserName with us? Is it possible that a character encoding issue expanded the length out? E.g. Salesforce sees it as 80 characters in one encoding, but the external tool sees it as 81 characters in a different encoding.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, we have Apex webservice that creates user record in Salesforce, so it gets triggered by internal.

Comment: OK, can you please share the problem UserName and the Apex webservice code that creates the User record? You should be able to edit this into you question.

Answer (score 1):

[This is not true](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_fields.htm):

> **Name**   Combined first name, middle name (beta), last name, and suffix (beta) of user, as displayed on the user detail page.
>
> **First Name** First name of user, as displayed on the user edit page. Up to 40 characters are allowed in this field.
>
> **Middle Name**    Middle name of the user, as displayed on the user edit page. Up to 40 characters are allowed for this field.
>
> **Last Name**  Last name of user, as displayed on the user edit page. Up to 80 characters are allowed in this field.
>
> **Suffix** Name suffix of the user, as displayed on the user edit page. Up to 40 characters are allowed for this field.

So potential **max length for the User Name could be 200** (40+40+80+40) characters (with Enabled `Name Suffixes for Person Names`) or 120 with the standard First + Last Name combination. *80 characters is a hard limit for the `Name` field on `Custom Object`*

Comment: The field is `Username`, not `User Name`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, my fault.